# Converting an array of array to a single array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
 let a = [
      ["base-certificate", 60, 3, 2022],
      ["case-certificate", 1, 3, 2022],
      ["standard-certificate", 7, 3, 2022],
    ];
```

I want to transform it to look like this:

```
[{x:[3, 2022], base: 60, case:1, standard: 7}]
```

I tried using the map method on the array like:

```js
let a = [
  ["base-certificate", 60, 3, 2022],
  ["case-certificate", 1, 3, 2022],
  ["standard-certificate", 7, 3, 2022],
];

let result = a.map((elem) => {
  let obj = {};
  elem.forEach((e, i) => {
    obj["x"] = [e[2], e[3]];
    obj[e[0]] = e[1];
  });
  return obj;
});
console.log(result);
```

The code above did not get the desired output.
what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Do you really need to put the resulting object inside an array?

Comment: I want to use the result in chart.js, and in chartjs data are usually in array, but i guess its not compulsory i could find a way around it

Comment: What criteria is used to form the `x` array? What if the ends of the existing three arrays differ rather than all ending with `3, 2022`?

Comment: the data consistes of a date time object it will be the same for the day, month and week only the year would be single: like i could have week 9 of 2022, like 9, 2022; and in case of year it is only year: 2022

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both the `map` and the `forEach`, you can remove the outer map.

Also if you want to remove the "-certificate" part, you can use a `split`.

Something like this should work

```js
let a = [
  ["base-certificate", 60, 3, 2022],
  ["case-certificate", 1, 3, 2022],
  ["standard-certificate", 7, 3, 2022],
];

let obj = {};
a.forEach((e, i) => {
  obj["x"] = [e[2], e[3]];
  obj[e[0].split('-')[0]] = e[1];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

`map()` is for creating an array. You just want one object, you should declare it outside the loop and use `forEach()` to fill it in. You don't need nested loops.

You can use `replace()` to remove `-certificate` from the names.

```js
let a = [
  ["base-certificate", 60, 3, 2022],
  ["case-certificate", 1, 3, 2022],
  ["standard-certificate", 7, 3, 2022],
];

let obj = {};

a.forEach((e, i) => {
  obj["x"] = [e[2], e[3]];
  obj[e[0].replace('-certificate', '')] = e[1];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = [
  ["base-certificate", 60, 3, 2022],
  ["case-certificate", 1, 3, 2022],
  ["standard-certificate", 7, 3, 2022],
];

let obj = {};
a.forEach((e) => {
    obj["x"] = [e[2], e[3]];
    obj[e[0].replace('-certificate',"")] = e[1];
});
console.log([obj]);
```